# How to remove emoji and other language in a DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, unicode, emoji

I got a dataframe as follows:

| Title | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 補水法 | Skin Care |
| 現貨 | รีบจัดด่วน‼️ ราคาเฉพาะรอบนี Test |

I tried to use the regex:

```
df1['Post Title'] = df1['Post Title'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', regex=True)
df1['Post Detail'] = df1['Post Detail'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', regex=True)
```

It successfully removes the emojis. However, it only saves for the English but not the Chinese.

I would like to remove all the emojis and languages neither Chinese nor English.

Expected result:

| Title | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 補水法 | Skin Care |
| 現貨 | Test |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added what I have tried so far

Comment: Can you post the desired output? I am assuming you wish to save languages but not emojis. Right?

Comment: Posted the expected result

Comment: Do you mean you only want to keep letters and whitespaces only? What about punctuation? I mean to say it is much simpler to match specific type of chars rather than removing emojis.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It will be good if punctuation is kept also

Comment: @Hang Any Unicode punctuation, or ASCII punctuation only?

Comment: For example, these kinds of punctuation: 。，、\%！？「」（）.
Are these Unicode? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, I see you need full Unicode support. I guess PyPi regex module would be a much better fit for you here, however, I will add the code for `re`. I hope it will be enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245782/discussion-between-hang-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the demoji library in python. For using do a pip install

```
 pip install demoji
```

Than

```
 import demoji
 df = df.applymap(lambda x: demoji.replace(x,''))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the solution contains two parts:

1. Remove emojis. Emojis can be removed by unicodes. The detailed emoji unicode list can be downloaded from http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html. It is recommended to utilizing exsiting packages to obtain the list like `emoji`. For example, with `emoji`, we can write following code. Tools like `demoji` and `cleantext` implement their methods in a similar way.

```
>>>
... from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI
... df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": ["補水法", " 現貨 "], "Content": ["Skin Care", "รีบจัดด่วน‼️ ราคาเฉพาะรอบนี Test"]})
... def remove_emoji(text):
...     emojis = UNICODE_EMOJI["en"]
...     if isinstance(emojis, str):
...         emojis = [emojis]
...     result = text
...     for x in emojis:
...         result = result.replace(x, "")
...     return result
... df = df.applymap(lambda x: remove_emoji(x))
... print(df)
  Title                         Content
0   補水法                       Skin Care
1   現貨   รีบจัดด่วน ราคาเฉพาะรอบนี Test
```

2. Remove Non-English or Non-Chinese Characters. One possible way to do it is utilizing some language detection tools like `langid`, `langdetect` and so on. For example, with following code, the content with Thai language will be removed.

```
>>> 
... import langid
... df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": ["補水法", " 現貨 "], "Content": ["Skin Care", "รีบจัดด่วน‼️ ราคาเฉพาะรอบนี Test"]})
... df = df.applymap(lambda x: '' if ((langid.classify(x)[0] != 'zh') and (langid.classify(x)[0] != 'en')) else x)

>>> print(df)

    Title    Content
0    補水法  Skin Care
1   現貨
```

If you want to acheive a more fine-grained result, say, you desire the result as below. I think you also need to tokenize the content. For Chinese tokenization, you can refer to https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/blob/master/sacrebleu/tokenizers/tokenizer_zh.py, which also includes unicode details of Hanzi.

```
  Title       Content
0   補水法    Skin Care
1   現貨      Test
```

Comment: That's great! Yes, I may need to tokenize the content, thanks for pasting the link for ref

Comment: @Hang I use language detection at work almost every day and there is a great chance a word language is not detected accurately - in your case, the word whose language was not correctly identified will not be kept. Note `langid` is not safe, `pycld2` is better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I should better use `pycld2` rather than `langid` to detect characters?

Comment: @Hang No, do not use any, this approach won't help you much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay. I guess regex would be enough for me at this moment

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all English and Chinese words and join with a space:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['補水法', ' 現貨 ', 'Text, text'], 'Content':['Skin Care', 'รีบจัดด่วน‼️ ราคาเฉพาะรอบนี Test', 'More text!!!']})

pPunct = r'!-/\:-@\[-`\{-~\u00A1-\u00A9\u00AB\u00AC\u00AE-\u00B1\u00B4\u00B6-\u00B8\u00BB\u00BF\u00D7\u00F7\u02C2-\u02C5\u02D2-\u02DF\u02E5-\u02EB\u02ED\u02EF-\u02FF\u0375\u037E\u0384\u0385\u0387\u03F6\u0482\u055A-\u055F\u0589\u058A\u058D-\u058F\u05BE\u05C0\u05C3\u05C6\u05F3\u05F4\u0606-\u060F\u061B\u061D-\u061F\u066A-\u066D\u06D4\u06DE\u06E9\u06FD\u06FE\u0700-\u070D\u07F6-\u07F9\u07FE\u07FF\u0830-\u083E\u085E\u0888\u0964\u0965\u0970\u09F2\u09F3\u09FA\u09FB\u09FD\u0A76\u0AF0\u0AF1\u0B70\u0BF3-\u0BFA\u0C77\u0C7F\u0C84\u0D4F\u0D79\u0DF4\u0E3F\u0E4F\u0E5A\u0E5B\u0F01-\u0F17\u0F1A-\u0F1F\u0F34\u0F36\u0F38\u0F3A-\u0F3D\u0F85\u0FBE-\u0FC5\u0FC7-\u0FCC\u0FCE-\u0FDA\u104A-\u104F\u109E\u109F\u10FB\u1360-\u1368\u1390-\u1399\u1400\u166D\u166E\u169B\u169C\u16EB-\u16ED\u1735\u1736\u17D4-\u17D6\u17D8-\u17DB\u1800-\u180A\u1940\u1944\u1945\u19DE-\u19FF\u1A1E\u1A1F\u1AA0-\u1AA6\u1AA8-\u1AAD\u1B5A-\u1B6A\u1B74-\u1B7E\u1BFC-\u1BFF\u1C3B-\u1C3F\u1C7E\u1C7F\u1CC0-\u1CC7\u1CD3\u1FBD\u1FBF-\u1FC1\u1FCD-\u1FCF\u1FDD-\u1FDF\u1FED-\u1FEF\u1FFD\u1FFE\u2010-\u2027\u2030-\u205E\u207A-\u207E\u208A-\u208E\u20A0-\u20C0\u2100\u2101\u2103-\u2106\u2108\u2109\u2114\u2116-\u2118\u211E-\u2123\u2125\u2127\u2129\u212E\u213A\u213B\u2140-\u2144\u214A-\u214D\u214F\u218A\u218B\u2190-\u2426\u2440-\u244A\u249C-\u24E9\u2500-\u2775\u2794-\u2B73\u2B76-\u2B95\u2B97-\u2BFF\u2CE5-\u2CEA\u2CF9-\u2CFC\u2CFE\u2CFF\u2D70\u2E00-\u2E2E\u2E30-\u2E5D\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u2FF0-\u2FFB\u3001-\u3004\u3008-\u3020\u3030\u3036\u3037\u303D-\u303F\u309B\u309C\u30A0\u30FB\u3190\u3191\u3196-\u319F\u31C0-\u31E3\u3200-\u321E\u322A-\u3247\u3250\u3260-\u327F\u328A-\u32B0\u32C0-\u33FF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\uA490-\uA4C6\uA4FE\uA4FF\uA60D-\uA60F\uA673\uA67E\uA6F2-\uA6F7\uA700-\uA716\uA720\uA721\uA789\uA78A\uA828-\uA82B\uA836-\uA839\uA874-\uA877\uA8CE\uA8CF\uA8F8-\uA8FA\uA8FC\uA92E\uA92F\uA95F\uA9C1-\uA9CD\uA9DE\uA9DF\uAA5C-\uAA5F\uAA77-\uAA79\uAADE\uAADF\uAAF0\uAAF1\uAB5B\uAB6A\uAB6B\uABEB\uFB29\uFBB2-\uFBC2\uFD3E-\uFD4F\uFDCF\uFDFC-\uFDFF\uFE10-\uFE19\uFE30-\uFE52\uFE54-\uFE66\uFE68-\uFE6B\uFF01-\uFF0F\uFF1A-\uFF20\uFF3B-\uFF40\uFF5B-\uFF65\uFFE0-\uFFE6\uFFE8-\uFFEE\uFFFC\uFFFD\U00010100-\U00010102\U00010137-\U0001013F\U00010179-\U00010189\U0001018C-\U0001018E\U00010190-\U0001019C\U000101A0\U000101D0-\U000101FC\U0001039F\U000103D0\U0001056F\U00010857\U00010877\U00010878\U0001091F\U0001093F\U00010A50-\U00010A58\U00010A7F\U00010AC8\U00010AF0-\U00010AF6\U00010B39-\U00010B3F\U00010B99-\U00010B9C\U00010EAD\U00010F55-\U00010F59\U00010F86-\U00010F89\U00011047-\U0001104D\U000110BB\U000110BC\U000110BE-\U000110C1\U00011140-\U00011143\U00011174\U00011175\U000111C5-\U000111C8\U000111CD\U000111DB\U000111DD-\U000111DF\U00011238-\U0001123D\U000112A9\U0001144B-\U0001144F\U0001145A\U0001145B\U0001145D\U000114C6\U000115C1-\U000115D7\U00011641-\U00011643\U00011660-\U0001166C\U000116B9\U0001173C-\U0001173F\U0001183B\U00011944-\U00011946\U000119E2\U00011A3F-\U00011A46\U00011A9A-\U00011A9C\U00011A9E-\U00011AA2\U00011C41-\U00011C45\U00011C70\U00011C71\U00011EF7\U00011EF8\U00011FD5-\U00011FF1\U00011FFF\U00012470-\U00012474\U00012FF1\U00012FF2\U00016A6E\U00016A6F\U00016AF5\U00016B37-\U00016B3F\U00016B44\U00016B45\U00016E97-\U00016E9A\U00016FE2\U0001BC9C\U0001BC9F\U0001CF50-\U0001CFC3\U0001D000-\U0001D0F5\U0001D100-\U0001D126\U0001D129-\U0001D164\U0001D16A-\U0001D16C\U0001D183\U0001D184\U0001D18C-\U0001D1A9\U0001D1AE-\U0001D1EA\U0001D200-\U0001D241\U0001D245\U0001D300-\U0001D356\U0001D6C1\U0001D6DB\U0001D6FB\U0001D715\U0001D735\U0001D74F\U0001D76F\U0001D789\U0001D7A9\U0001D7C3\U0001D800-\U0001D9FF\U0001DA37-\U0001DA3A\U0001DA6D-\U0001DA74\U0001DA76-\U0001DA83\U0001DA85-\U0001DA8B\U0001E14F\U0001E2FF\U0001E95E\U0001E95F\U0001ECAC\U0001ECB0\U0001ED2E\U0001EEF0\U0001EEF1\U0001F000-\U0001F02B\U0001F030-\U0001F093\U0001F0A0-\U0001F0AE\U0001F0B1-\U0001F0BF\U0001F0C1-\U0001F0CF\U0001F0D1-\U0001F0F5\U0001F10D-\U0001F1AD\U0001F1E6-\U0001F202\U0001F210-\U0001F23B\U0001F240-\U0001F248\U0001F250\U0001F251\U0001F260-\U0001F265\U0001F300-\U0001F6D7\U0001F6DD-\U0001F6EC\U0001F6F0-\U0001F6FC\U0001F700-\U0001F773\U0001F780-\U0001F7D8\U0001F7E0-\U0001F7EB\U0001F7F0\U0001F800-\U0001F80B\U0001F810-\U0001F847\U0001F850-\U0001F859\U0001F860-\U0001F887\U0001F890-\U0001F8AD\U0001F8B0\U0001F8B1\U0001F900-\U0001FA53\U0001FA60-\U0001FA6D\U0001FA70-\U0001FA74\U0001FA78-\U0001FA7C\U0001FA80-\U0001FA86\U0001FA90-\U0001FAAC\U0001FAB0-\U0001FABA\U0001FAC0-\U0001FAC5\U0001FAD0-\U0001FAD9\U0001FAE0-\U0001FAE7\U0001FAF0-\U0001FAF6\U0001FB00-\U0001FB92\U0001FB94-\U0001FBCA'
pLatin = r'A-Za-z\u00AA\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8\u02E0-\u02E4\u1D00-\u1D25\u1D2C-\u1D5C\u1D62-\u1D65\u1D6B-\u1D77\u1D79-\u1DBE\u1E00-\u1EFF\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u212A\u212B\u2132\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u2C60-\u2C7F\uA722-\uA787\uA78B-\uA7CA\uA7D0\uA7D1\uA7D3\uA7D5-\uA7D9\uA7F2-\uA7FF\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB64\uAB66-\uAB69\uFB00-\uFB06\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\U00010780-\U00010785\U00010787-\U000107B0\U000107B2-\U000107BA\U0001DF00-\U0001DF1E'
pHan = r'\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\U00016FE2\U00016FE3\U00016FF0\U00016FF1\U00020000-\U0002A6DF\U0002A700-\U0002B738\U0002B740-\U0002B81D\U0002B820-\U0002CEA1\U0002CEB0-\U0002EBE0\U0002F800-\U0002FA1D\U00030000-\U0003134A'
pEmojiEx = r'0-9\u00A9\u00AE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26A7\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299\U0001F004\U0001F0CF\U0001F170\U0001F171\U0001F17E\U0001F17F\U0001F18E\U0001F191-\U0001F19A\U0001F1E6-\U0001F1FF\U0001F201\U0001F202\U0001F21A\U0001F22F\U0001F232-\U0001F23A\U0001F250\U0001F251\U0001F300-\U0001F321\U0001F324-\U0001F393\U0001F396\U0001F397\U0001F399-\U0001F39B\U0001F39E-\U0001F3F0\U0001F3F3-\U0001F3F5\U0001F3F7-\U0001F4FD\U0001F4FF-\U0001F53D\U0001F549-\U0001F54E\U0001F550-\U0001F567\U0001F56F\U0001F570\U0001F573-\U0001F57A\U0001F587\U0001F58A-\U0001F58D\U0001F590\U0001F595\U0001F596\U0001F5A4\U0001F5A5\U0001F5A8\U0001F5B1\U0001F5B2\U0001F5BC\U0001F5C2-\U0001F5C4\U0001F5D1-\U0001F5D3\U0001F5DC-\U0001F5DE\U0001F5E1\U0001F5E3\U0001F5E8\U0001F5EF\U0001F5F3\U0001F5FA-\U0001F64F\U0001F680-\U0001F6C5\U0001F6CB-\U0001F6D2\U0001F6D5-\U0001F6D7\U0001F6DD-\U0001F6E5\U0001F6E9\U0001F6EB\U0001F6EC\U0001F6F0\U0001F6F3-\U0001F6FC\U0001F7E0-\U0001F7EB\U0001F7F0\U0001F90C-\U0001F93A\U0001F93C-\U0001F945\U0001F947-\U0001F9FF\U0001FA70-\U0001FA74\U0001FA78-\U0001FA7C\U0001FA80-\U0001FA86\U0001FA90-\U0001FAAC\U0001FAB0-\U0001FABA\U0001FAC0-\U0001FAC5\U0001FAD0-\U0001FAD9\U0001FAE0-\U0001FAE7\U0001FAF0-\U0001FAF6'
pat = fr'[{pHan}{pLatin}{pPunct}]+'

df = df.replace(fr'[{pEmojiEx}]+', '', regex=True)
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.findall(pat).str.join(" ")
df['Content'] = df['Content'].str.findall(pat).str.join(" ")
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Title       Content
0         補水法     Skin Care
1          現貨          Test
2  Text, text  More text!!!
```

What it does is:

- `df.replace(fr'[{pEmojiEx}]+', '', regex=True)` removes all chars that are marked with `Emoji` Unicode property (these include digits, but I removed `*` and `#`)
- `.str.findall(fr'[{pHan}{pLatin}{pPunct}]+').str.join(" ")` extracts chunks of one or more Latin, Han or any punctuation chars and joins them with a space.

Comment: Seems I can use the pattern `\p{Han}` to replace the variable `han` you created?

Comment: @Hang I converted `\p{Han}` / `\p{Latin}` into `re`-compliant pattern. `re` does not support Unicode property classes.

Comment: Will this cater to the punctuation I mentioned?

Comment: @Hang Now, yes.